# Magento 2.4.6 cannot be accessed with GET method

Tags: magento

I'm having thousands of this entries in my debug.log in Magento

[2023-09-27T06:08:35.426496+00:00] main.DEBUG: URI '/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zZWVkczI0LmF0L2Ntcy9ub3JvdXRlL2luZGV4L3VlbmMvYUhSMGNITTZMeTl6WldWa2N6STBMbUYwTDJOaGRHRnNiMmR6WldGeVkyZ3ZjbVZ6ZFd4MEwybHVaR1Y0THo5allYUTlOQ1p4UFdGallYQjFiR052L3Byb2R1Y3QvOTQ2Ni8~/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost) [] []

[2023-09-27T06:08:35.429371+00:00] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []

Can somebody help with this?